# How to swap two tables in postgres database with constraints and indexes?

Tags: postgresql

I  want to maintain two tables primary and secondary. The API services serves the clients from the primary table. When i have to repopulate the tables i write to a new table and change the secondary and primaries like below.

```
BEGIN;

DROP TABLE "public.table_secondary"
ALTER TABLE "public.table_primary" RENAME TO "public.table_secondary";
ALTER TABLE "public.table_new" RENAME TO "public.table_primary";


COMMIT;
```

This way the API service wont go down when the tables are repopulated.
The question that i have is what happens to constraints, indexes and sequence used for the table_primary and table_secondary.
For the table_primary, the additional DDL statements used during creation are:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.seq1

ALTER TABLE public.table_primary ADD COLUMN id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('seq1');

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.table_primary ADD CONSTRAINT pkeyconstraint PRIMARY KEY (id);

ALTER TABLE public.table_primary  ADD CONSTRAINT uniqueidfk FOREIGN KEY (uniqueid) REFERENCES externaltable2 (id);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS index ON table_primary (uniqueid);
```

How should the additional constraints and indexes handled when we do a swap of the tables?

Thanks in advance for reply

Comment: Lol, yeah, I'm figuring out this one too. Partitions offer one way. But existing tables cannot be set up for partitioning.